# Count non-empty leaves in a binary tree

Tags: tree, prolog, binary-tree

Basically want to find the number of non-empty leaves in a binary tree. The term we use was `tree(Element,Left,Right).`

We use predicate leaves(T,N) be true if N is the number of non-empty leaves in a given binary tree T, where a non-empty leaf is a sub-tree different from void that has only void nodes as children.

For example :

```
? - leaves(tree(a, tree(b,tree(d,void,void),void), tree(c,void,void)), X).
```

should return X=2

This is what I got so far,

```
leaves(void, 0).
leaves(tree(E,L,R), X) :- leave(L, L1), leave(R, R1).
```

Having trouble counting the number of non-empty leaves.

Comment: Well that is close to nothing. Please at least explain in *words* how you would calculate the number of non-empty leaves (What is by the way a non-empty leave?).

Comment: what is a tree? what is a tree node? what is a leaf? if you know it, you can count it.

Comment: Break it down. For instance, what does the predicate clause look.like for a subtree that is a single leaf?

Comment: Perhaps `X is L1+R1`?